# Doctrine 2 update data into Database but not update data into Entity

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm

Working on zend framework 2 with doctrine 2.

While unit testing, I use a 'testing database' to add, edit and delete values from.

The issue was that I add a new entity, ok.
After I add the new entity, witch works perfecty, i tried to Update the entity.

```
//set all values
$this->getEntityManager->persist($dataEntity);
$this->getEntityManager->flush()
```

When I Try to retrieve the updated data using:

```
    $produtoAcessorioCompareEntity = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Administrador\Entity\ProdutoAcessorio')->findOneBy(array(
        'idProdutoAcessorio' => $produtoAcessorioEntity->getIdProdutoAcessorio()
    ));
```

But this cached the old data from ADD Method and not updated the data for the new Entity $produtoAcessorioCompareEntity, I got the old values.

When I check the database, the new values are there. So should have one trick to reorganize loaded entities that I'm probably missing.

How can I update the Working Entities After Persist and Flush, to get the new values by $this->getEntityManager->getRepository() instead open a new connection?

Comment: $entityManager->clear();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$this->getEntityManager()->refresh($entity);

Answer (score 1):

Well, you code does not seem to be wrong, however, you can try with the `find()` method:

```
$produtoAcessorioCompareEntity = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->find('Administrador\Entit\ProdutoAcessorio', $produtoAcessorioEntity->getIdProdutoAcessorio());
```